# Construct diagonal matrix using bigalgebra

Tags: r, matrix

I'd like to construct a bigger diagonal matrix from a vector. I installed the `bigalgebra` package, but it don't have the `diag` function. In addition, how to make the inverse (`solve`) and transpose (`t`) to big matrices.

```
v <- runif(42109)
V <- diag(v)
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 13.2 Gb
```

Answer (score 1):

If sparse matrices are an option, you can use the Matrix package (supplied with R).

```
library(Matrix)
V <- Matrix(0, nrow=42109, ncol=42109)
diag(V) <- v
```

Comment: Thanks man! But, how to solve the problem: `Cholmod error 'out of memory' at file ../Core/cholmod_memory.c, line 147`. It happens when I go to realize the product `sqrt(V)%*%X%*%V%*%t(X)%*%sqrt(V)`, where `X` is a sparse matrix too.